# Java android: When I re-click on the button, the App closes directly

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have a problem.. When I launch my app and I click on the button le App closes directly...
I don't find how to fix the problem... Have you an idea ?

Sometimes, the app workly whith succes, but when I re click, the app closes directly :(

My code:

```
public class AsyncBigCalculActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mButton;
    private TextView data;
    private String dataImplode;
    PostTask PostTask = new PostTask(this);


    public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Telephone: "+phoneNumber+"\n Message: "+message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        // On récupère les composants de notre layout
        data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLaunch);




        // On met un Listener sur le bouton
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AsyncBigCalculActivity activity;
                    PostTask.execute();


            }
        });         
}

       // The definition of our task class
       private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

           private AsyncBigCalculActivity activty;

       public PostTask(AsyncBigCalculActivity activty)
       {
          this.activty = activty;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();

       }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


          return getServerData("http://site.com","etat","nok");
       }

       @Override
       protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
          super.onProgressUpdate(values);

       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);

          if(result != null && result.length()>0){
              String[] res = result.split(";-;");
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res[0]+"\n"+res[1]+"\n"+res[2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              AsyncBigCalculActivity.this.sendSMS("0000000000", "Hello World !");
          }

       }
       }


private String getServerData(String returnString,String post, String valeur) {


        String Num ="";
        String Message ="";
        String Id ="";

        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(post,valeur));

        // Envoie de la commande http
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(returnString);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convertion de la requÃªte en string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Parse les donnÃ©es JSON
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){


                JSONObject data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Num = data.getString("destinataire_mobile");
                Message = data.getString("destinataire_message");
                Id = data.getString("id");

                dataImplode = Num+";-;"+Message+";-;"+Id;



                if(((Num.length())==12) && (((Message.length())>=2)) && Num != "" && Message !=""){





                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(Message);
                    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(Num, null, parts, null, null);


                    getServerData("site.com","id",Id);


                }

            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return dataImplode;         
    }

}
```

My Logcat:

```
01-22 11:29:58.219: I/global(6771): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
01-22 11:29:58.619: E/log_tag(6771): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-22 11:30:21.929: D/AndroidRuntime(6771): Shutting down VM
01-22 11:30:21.929: W/dalvikvm(6771): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4e228)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:553)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at com.arnaud.AsyncBigCalculActivity$1.onClick(AsyncBigCalculActivity.java:68)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14330)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5005)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-22 11:30:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(6771):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks you !!

Comment: Its because you are trying to start a AsyncTask which is already running. To avoid this once the Aysnctask is started the button has to be disabled and only at the end it has to be enabled.

Comment: you are not allowed to run an Asynctask twice (note that i'm only paraphrasing the exception message)

Answer (score 1):

use a boolean flag to control user click on Button an prevent to start AsyncTask again if it's executing already . change your code as :

```
public class AsyncBigCalculActivity extends Activity {
      // your code here...
   public static boolean status=false;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        PostTask = new PostTask(this);

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLaunch);
        // On met un Listener sur le bouton
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               if(!status){
                AsyncBigCalculActivity activity;
                   status=true;
                    PostTask.execute();
                }
                else{
                        // show message here
                 }

            }
        });         
}

       // The definition of our task class
       private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
            status=true;  //<< make status true 
       }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

          return getServerData("http://site.com","etat","nok");
       }

       @Override
       protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
          super.onProgressUpdate(values);

       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);

          status=false; //<< make status false 
       } 
       }
```

and second way is use [AsyncTask.Status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html) and prevent user to start it again if already running

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation of AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) `The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)`.

This means that you have to create a new object of your PostTask every time you want to run it. If you do not need to refer to the said object while or after it runs, just use this to start your task:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
   if(!status){
      AsyncBigCalculActivity activity;
         status=true;
         new PostTask.execute(); // create new instance of PostTask and execute it.
   }
   else {
      // show message here
   }
}
```

Or if you need to hold a reference to it:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
   if(!status){
      AsyncBigCalculActivity activity;
         status=true;
         postTask = new PostTask();
         postTask.execute();
   }
   else {
      // show message here
   }
}
```

Where postTask is `PostTask postTask = null;`. It's not the best idea to name your variables the same as your class name.